# How to keep multiple uicollectionview controls in same Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I  want to keep multiple uicollectionview controls in same Viewcontroller .pl suggest me code or any links

Comment: Give different tags to both collection controls, and in delegate methods check for particular collection control by tag.

Comment: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial use this

Comment: I want to add multiple uicollectionview like a Subview

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "tag" value of both collection view and then check the tag value using the following code:

```
if (collectionView.tag == 0) {
    // collection view 1
}
else if (collectionView.tag == 1) {
    // collection view 2
}
```

You can set the tag value in the interface builder or in the code as well. using `setTag:` method.

Answer (score 1):

It just an idea

Intialize like this:

```
 CGRect mainFrame = self.view.frame;


 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionView1=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, mainFrame.origin.y , 320, 250) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [collectionView1 setDataSource:self];
    [collectionView1 setDelegate:self];

    [collectionView1 registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    [collectionView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:collectionView1];

    [collectionView1 reloadData];



    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout2=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionview2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, mainFrame.origin.y +  270, 320, mainFrame.size.height-280) collectionViewLayout:layout2];

    [collectionview2 setDataSource:self];
    [collectionview2 setDelegate:self];

    [collectionview2 registerClass:[Cell2 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"destCellIdetifier"];

    [collectionview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    [self.view collectionview2];

    [collectionview2 reloadData];
```

Write datasource and delegate like below

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (collectionView == collectionView1) {
        return 18;
    }
    else
        return 8;
}


// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell1 = nil;

    if ([collectionView isEqual:collectionView1]) {
        cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell1.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.item];
    }
    else {

        Cell2 *cell2 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"destCellIdetifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell2.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.item];
        return cell2;

    }

    return cell1;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(65, 60);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 10, 10.0f, 10.0f);
}
```

Comment: what is mainframe which variable